# Apache httpd won't start

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd, rsa

I'm unable to start apache on El Capitan. Output of apachectl restart is:

```
[Mon Apr 18 19:47:32 2016] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:8443 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Apr 18 19:47:32 2016] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:8080 has no VirtualHosts
httpd not running, trying to start
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8443
```

Output from my apache error_log:

```
    [Mon Apr 18 19:47:33 2016] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Apr 18 19:47:33 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Apr 18 19:47:33 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.dev' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Apr 18 19:47:33 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Apr 18 19:47:33 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.dev' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Apr 18 19:47:33 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
```

I've tried restoring my httpd.conf file from the original version in /etc/apache2/original, but I get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

> 48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   [::]:8443

means that there is something listening on that port on the localhost interface. Apache is probably not stopped, so it cannot start either. Try stopping it, if that does not work or you cannot get it to stop, try rebooting your mac osx host.